# Django Class based view get_context not finding get request

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm editing django allauth to change the template when the device is mobile, I've tried both using the `django-mobile` `request.mobile` and `request.GET.get('mobile')` both don't work the url is `/accounts/signup/?mobile=true`
Here's what I've got so far

```
class LoginView(RedirectAuthenticatedUserMixin,
                AjaxCapableProcessFormViewMixin,
                FormView):
    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = "account/login.html"
    success_url = None
    redirect_field_name = "next"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        success_url = self.get_success_url()
        return form.login(self.request, redirect_url=success_url)

    def get_success_url(self):
        # Explicitly passed ?next= URL takes precedence
        ret = (get_next_redirect_url(self.request,
                                     self.redirect_field_name)
               or self.success_url)
        return ret

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ret = super(LoginView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        signup_url = passthrough_next_redirect_url(self.request,
                                                   reverse("account_signup"),
                                                   self.redirect_field_name)
        redirect_field_value = self.request.REQUEST \
            .get(self.redirect_field_name)
        if self.request.GET.get('mobile'):
            self.template_name = 'mobile/sign_up.html'
        ret.update({"signup_url": signup_url,
                    "site": Site.objects.get_current(),
                    "redirect_field_name": self.redirect_field_name,
                    "redirect_field_value": redirect_field_value})
        return ret
```

Comment: Are you sure your problem is really the conditional statement? Could it be that by the time `get_context_data(…)` is called, the template name is already determined? Either way you would be better off overriding `get_template_names(…)`.

Comment: @patrys it worked you should post this as an answer

Comment: I have now posted this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you override `.get_template_names(…)` instead of `.get_context_data(…)`, you will get a much cleaner solution and a chance to replace the template name at the precise point it is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You have redundant space symbol here:

```
redirect_field_value = self.request.REQUEST \
    .get(self.redirect_field_name) #       ^ space should be removed!
```

Comment: This is not an answer, it should be a comment or an edit.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But in comment we can't insert formatted code and edit should be bigger that 1 symbol removal. So I wrote it as answer. If it is not answer (i.e. the correction didn't help to solve the issue) — probably it will be better to just delete it?